# Commutation of pushforward and pullback along cartesian squares

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, coherent-sheaves

I am sure this is well-known, but I cannot find a reference. Consider a cartesian square
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
P @>{v}>> X\\
@V{g}VV @VV{f}V \\
Z @>{u}>> Y
\end{CD}$$
where all morphisms are morphisms of algebraic varieties over a field. It is known (e.g. Harthorne, III.9.3) that when $u$ is flat and $f$ is proper, there is a natural isomorphism $$u^\ast f_\ast\overset{\sim}{\longrightarrow} g_\ast v^\ast$$
of functors $Coh_X\to Coh_Z$.

> **Question**. Is there also an isomorphism $v_\ast g^\ast\cong f^\ast u_\ast$ of functors $QCoh_Z\to QCoh_X$?

Assuming $Z$ is proper (and $Y$ separated), we can restrict attention to coherent sheaves.
I am actually interested in the case when $u$ is \'etale and $f$ is a closed immersion, but I do not think this specialization is of any real help.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are saying is (almost) true: it works in the derived category.

Below, for a scheme map $\alpha$, we denote $\alpha^*$ to be the derived functor $\mathsf{L}\alpha^*$ and denote $\alpha_*$ to be the derived functor $\mathsf{R}\alpha_*$. Also, $\mathbf{D}_\mathsf{qc}(-)$ denotes the derived category of sheaves of modules with quasi-coherent cohomology.

We adopt your notation, but generalize a bit: let $X,Y,P,Z$ be quasi-separated schemes, and suppose they fit into a commutative square $\sigma$:
$$\begin{CD}
  P @>v>> X\\
  @VgVV \sigma @VVfV\\
  Z @>u>> Y
\end{CD}$$
where all maps are quasi-compact and quasi-separated.

We say $\sigma$ is

- *independent* if the functorial map
  $$u^*f_* \overset{\sim}{\longrightarrow} g_*v^*$$
  of functors $\mathbf{D}_\mathsf{qc}(X) \to \mathbf{D}_\mathsf{qc}(Z)$ is an isomorphism;
- $'$-*independent* if the functorial map
  $$f^*u_* \overset{\sim}{\longrightarrow} v_*g^*$$
  of functors $\mathbf{D}_\mathsf{qc}(Z) \to \mathbf{D}_\mathsf{qc}(X)$ is an isomorphism;
- *tor-independent* if $\sigma$ is cartesian and for all pairs of points $z \in Z$, $x \in X$ such that $y := u(z) = f(x)$,
  $$\operatorname{Tor}_i^{\mathcal{O}_{Y,y}}(\mathcal{O}_{Z,z},\mathcal{O}_{X,x}) = 0, \quad \text{for all}\ i > 0.$$

In this situation, the following theorem holds:

**Theorem** [[Lipman](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-85420-3), 3.10.3]**.** *The three independence conditions above are equivalent.*

The proof is a bit complicated, but the idea is you want to reduce to the affine case after showing the independence conditions above are local. Lipman then proceeds by showing that these three independence conditions are equivalent to being *Künneth-independent,* whose definition is a bit harder to state.

Comment: The derived version is very interesting, thank you! So in the case $f$ a closed immersion and $u$ flat, we have $Rf_\ast=0$ and $Lf^\ast=0$, so "independence" is actually visible without derived categories. But (if I understand correctly) it is not so for $\prime$-independence...

Comment: @Brenin I think you mean the higher pushforwards and pullbacks, but yes, "independence" is visible without derived categories in your case. But then, you do need the derived version for $'$-independence, since the zeroth cohomology of $\mathsf{L}f^*\mathsf{R}u_*$ and $\mathsf{R}v_*\mathsf{L}g^*$ will indeed by isomorphic, but no longer be the same as the non-derived versions $f^*u_*$ and $v_*g^*$.

Answer (score 1):

The condition that $f$ be proper is necessary to ensure that the direct image of a coherent sheaf is coherent.

Under more general conditions, the direct image of a quasicoherent sheaf is quasicoherent.

The standard reference for all this is, no doubt, EGA; EGA I, Prop. 9.2.1, Cor. 9.2.2 show that the image sheaf of a quasicoherent sheaf is quasicoherent.
  Ravi Vakil has a lovely set of notes on foundations of algebraic geometry in his webpage, based on EGA, that you may find useful (but it won't carry more than EGA on this topic).

The case of a closed immersion $f$ is especially easy: you simply deal with the affine case, where $f_*\tilde{M}$ is simply viewing $M$ as an $A$-module instead of an $A/I$-module.  There is an equivalence of quasicoherent modules that are isomorphic to $f_*F$ for $F$ on $X$ with those on $Y$ which are supported on $X$. Thus pulling back by $A\to B$ is the same as pulling back via $A/I \to B/IB$ and then pushing forward. The notation used is: $I$ is the ideal of a closed subscheme $X$ of $Spec(A)=Y$  (It suffices to reduce to the affine case for $f$, that's why the above settles the proof of equivalence you are seeking)

That's how one settles the desired equivalence in your case, with $u$ flat and $f$ a closed immersion in the case of quasicoherent sheaves.

In fact, with the generality you ask, one may use that every quasicoherent sheaf on a Noetherian scheme is a direct limit of quasicoherent subsheaves in order to obtain a proof of equivalence for quasicoherent sheaves, see e.g. these notes (based on EGA I.9, of course).

https://math.berkeley.edu/~mhaiman/math256-fall13-spring14/EGAI-9.pdf

Comment: Thank you so much! For the references as well... So for the case $u$ flat and $f$ closed immersion we have $v_\ast g^\ast\cong f^\ast u_\ast$, but where is flatness of $u$ needed in the argument you gave?

Comment: I think that you can do it for any $u$, to be honest.  If we think of the case where all varieties involved are affine, it is the famous property that tensoring an $A/I$-module $M$ over $B/IB$ is the same as tensoring it over $B$ and then viewing $B\otimes M$ as a $B/IB$-module.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what is going on. I am interested in $v_\ast g^\ast\overset{?}{\cong}f^\ast u_\ast$, not $u^\ast f_\ast\cong g_\ast v^\ast$. Maybe I am overlooking something, but it seems to me that in the affine case (say we base change $A\to A/I$ by $A\to B$), the question is: given a $B$-module $M$, are $M_A\otimes_AA/I$ and $M\otimes_BB/IB$ isomorphic as $A/I$-modules? Does that make sense?